# InvalidOperationException in Asp.Net MVC while using In-Memory Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, caching, memorycache

I need to apply `In-Memory Cache` on my website with`.NetFramework 4.5.2` but I get this exception:

> Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException: 'Resolution of the
>   dependency failed, type =
>   'Tranship.UI.Areas.Portal.Controllers.SearchResultController', name =
>   '(none)'. Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache, is an interface and
>   cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

I am using Asp.net MVC (not Core) and using `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory version 1.1.2` 
This is my cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tranship.Business.Core;
using Tranship.Business.Interface;
using Tranship.DataAccess.UnitOfWork;
using Tranship.Domain.Context;
using Tranship.Domain.Model;
using Tranship.DomainService.Interface;
using Tranship.ViewModel.Model;
using Tranship.ViewModel.Mapper;
using Tranship.ViewModel.Parameter;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace Tranship.DomainService.Core
{
    public class ScheduleDomainService : IScheduleDomainService
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache MemoryCache;
        private readonly string key = "TranshipMemoryCache";
        public BoundedContextUnitOfWork Context { get; set; }
        public IScheduleBiz ScheduleBiz { get; set; }
        public ScheduleDomainService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            Context = new BoundedContextUnitOfWork(new BoundedContext());
            ScheduleBiz = new ScheduleBiz(Context);
            MemoryCache = memoryCache;
        }
        public List<ScheduleViewModel> GetScheduleBySearchParameter(SearchTripParameters parameters)
        {
            DateTime from;
            DateTime to;
            List<ScheduleViewModel> cacheObject = new List<ScheduleViewModel>();
            if (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheObject))
            {
                // Cache is empty or timespan has been terminated
                cacheObject = ScheduleBiz.GetAll();
                MemoryCache.Set(key, cacheObject, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1)));
            }
            else
            {
                // Cache is full
                cacheObject = MemoryCache.Get(key) as List<ScheduleViewModel>;
            }
            return cacheObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Only a guess: Unity cannot resolve IMemoryCache. Maybe the registration for the implementation of ÌMemoryCache` is missing.

Comment: are you sure you added AddMemoryCache() on ConfigureServices at startup
check this 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2#using-imemorycache

Comment: @Ahmed Ghoniem AddMemoryCache() belongs to the .net Core. I am using Asp.Net MVC.

Comment: if I add container.RegisterType<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>(); registration it says that MemoryCacheOptions  registration is missing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to register `IMemoryCache` to `Unity` container

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer(); // your unity container

MemoryCacheOptions memoryCacheOptions = new MemoryCacheOptions
{
    //config your cache here
};

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache(Options.Create<MemoryCacheOptions>(memoryCacheOptions));
container.RegisterInstance<IMemoryCache>(memoryCache);
```

Answer (score -1):

To be able to use existing cache implementation based on .net 4.5.2 in .net core I've ported it to use **System.Runtime caching** instead of System Web. Works like a charm.

[Here's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.0)